# Akephalos: How to ignore SSL warnings?

Tags: ssl, cucumber, capybara, akephalos

I'm trying to set up Akephalos for use with Capybara. I ran into this
message when trying to `visit` the page I am trying to test:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated (NativeException)
(druby://127.0.0.1:35580) org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2042:in `send' 
(druby://127.0.0.1:35580) org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1417:in `loop' 
(druby://127.0.0.1:35580) org/jruby/RubyProc.java:268:in `call' 
(druby://127.0.0.1:35580) org/jruby/RubyProc.java:232:in `call'
```

I wonder if it has anything to do with the fact that we are using a
self-signed certificate. This is what my env.rb file looks like:

```
# Capybara configuration (using Akephalos)
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'capybara/cucumber'
require 'akephalos'
Capybara.javascript_driver = :akephalos
Capybara.default_driver = :akephalos
Capybara.register_driver :akephalos do |app|
  # available options:
  #   :ie6, :ie7, :ie8, :firefox_3, :firefox_3_6
  Capybara::Driver::Akephalos.new(app, :browser => :firefox_3_6)
end
World(Capybara)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the server is using a self-signed certificate, this can cause a warning/error such as 'peer not authenticated'.

The proper way around this problem is to specifically add the self-signed certificate to the trusted root store.

The wrong way around this problem is to turn off certificate verification.

I don't know the product you are using well enough to tell you how to do either of these things.